# An error while printing an array in textbox in Windows Application form

Tags: c#

Here's my code for one of the algorithm given by our professor. Everything is working fine except the last part of the program. I have to divide each element of the Statistics array by NumberofExperiments and assign that value to another array Frequency. But it's not happening so. The values assigned to Frequency array is always zero.  I have debugged the code and array Statistics has all the elements. So there's a problem only in the last part of the program. Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
      public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int[] Statistics  = new int[5];
    

    double P1;
    double P2;
    double P3;
    double P4;
    double P5;
    int NumberofExperiments;

    double SumofP;

    Random random = new Random();

    int k;
   

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        P1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        P2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
        P3 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        P4 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);

        NumberofExperiments = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);

        SumofP = P1 + P2 + P3 + P4;

        P5 = 1 - SumofP;

        textBox5.Text = P5.ToString();


        int i;

        for( i = 0; i <= NumberofExperiments;)
        {
            
            if (i < NumberofExperiments)
            {
                k = random.Next(0, 5);

                Statistics[k] = Statistics[k] + 1;
                i++;
                
            }

            else
            {
               double[] Frequency = new double[5]; //initializing an empty array 
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
          

                    Frequency[j] = Statistics[j] / NumberofExperiments; //The Problem is here. 
                   

                    textBox7.Text = Frequency[j].ToString();
                }
                break;
               


            }
            
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you're converting into to double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You initialise a new array every loop,
2. `Statistics` is of type `int`. Cast it to `double`:

   ```
   for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   {
       Frequency[j] = Statistics[j] / NumberofExperiments; //The Problem is here. 
       textBox7.Text = Frequency[j].ToString();
   }
   ```

you essentially empty the array every iteration. Take that outside of the loop, cast the division and it should be fine. Also to display all of the values and not just the last, you must ADD to the text of the `textBox` and not replace it entirely.

```
double[] Frequency = new double[5]; //Now its fine
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
     {
         Frequency[j] = (double)Statistics[j] / NumberofExperiments; 
                       
         textBox7.Text = textBox7.Text + " " + Frequency[j].ToString();
     }
```

Comment: It is this. Plus also think about the loops you have, instead of looping j inside the loop for i, complete the loop for i first then do the loop for j.

Comment: @bluevulture I did still all the values in Frequency array is 0;

Comment: @mikelegg No, I can't do that. Since the second loop starts when the condition of first loop gets false.

Comment: @snehashukla I see the problem. `Statistics` is an array of type `int`, therefore the division outputs an int. Change `Statistics` to type double or cast it to double. Edited the code.

Comment: @bluevulture it worked. But the textbox is printing just the last value of Frequency array. Not all the values. Can you help with the same?

Comment: @snehashukla You are changing the entire text of the textbox to a single value as you go through the loop; first to Frequency[0], then Frequency[1]... and so on. You must instead ADD to the textbox: `textBox7.Text = textBox7.Text + " " + Frequency[j].ToString();` You can replace the `" "` with `"\n"` if you want a newline.

Comment: @snehashukla if this answer resolved your problem, please do accept it.